# How to insert element of list a python into list?

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, append

I have a List

```
a = [['mf1234','james','22'],['mcs345','Anee','22']]
b = ['man','women]
```

i wanna insert the member of list b into a like

```
c = [['mf1234','james','22','man'],['mcs345','Anne','23','women]]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: i used some function of insert and append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to insert items in `b` at the end of the each list in `a`, [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is your way to go.

```
for idx,item in enumerate(b):
    a[idx].append(item)

print a
>>> [['mf1234', 'james', '22', 'man'], ['mcs345', 'Anee', '22', 'women']]
```